# LLamaIndex Chat engine restricting answers to context

Tags: large-language-model, llama-index

I am trying to have a chat engine by providing a context but I am getting answers outside the context too.
I tried the same thing with the query engine and seems to work fine, the problem is only with the chat engine. When I ask a question about Amazon or Google, I am getting the answer from LLM but what I am expecting is a message that the context did not have the information. This behavior is observed in the query engine

```
storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir="storage")
index=load_index_from_storage(storage_context,service_context=service_context)
chat_engine = index.as_chat_engine(
            chat_mode="context",
            memory=memory,
          verbose=True,            
        )
```

Thanks in advance for the help